# How to set proxy_pass on nginx

Tags: nginx

Bit of an nginx noob here. I'm trying to setup nginx to reverse proxy all web traffic to a locally running web server. Right now it works but it says the IP address of every logged in user is 127.0.0.1. I read some other posts that I need to set the `proxy_set_header Host $host;` correctly. I set this this, but users IPs are still 127.0.0.1. Can anyone tell by looking at my nginx.conf if I'm setting `proxy_set_header Host $host;` incorrectly? I think I need to set it in both server blocks, but I don't have a `location` block in the server that accepts traffic on port 80. Which is where I think it might be getting lost.

```
    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name www.myapp.com myapp.com;
       return 301 https://myapp.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
       listen 443;
       server_name _;
       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /web/ssl/cert.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /web/ssl/key.pem;

      location / {
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
       }

       location /robots.txt {
         alias /web/static/robots.txt;
      }

      }
```

Comment: Is your application actually looking for the IP address in the `X-Real-IP` header?

Answer (score 0):

Use;

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

This will add a new header to the backend server which your application will be able to see the original IP addresses.

You're along the right lines with `X-Real-IP`, in that this will do the same thing (providing that `$remote_addr` is actually the client's IP address). `X-Forwarded-For` is more universal though, and if your backend is running a standard off-the-shelf package, it may already know about it. Likewise, if your application isn't looking at `X-Real-IP` header, then it won't reflect.

Putting it bluntly, there's **no** way to override the `Remote-Addr` header at the backend, as this is set internally by most all web servers. You need to get your application to look in other headers if `Remote-Addr` is a local, private, or otherwise unrouteable IP address (127.0.0.1, 10.x.x.x, etc).

Comment: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` causes nginx to fail on restart for me

Comment: Oh, I forgot the semicolon. Still no dice though :(

Comment: More context on your backend setup is required at this point tbh. The configuration works and will pass the relevant information to the backend server. It's now up to how your application is perceiving the user, and whether it's even able to look at the correct headers (or if you're able to change the application's code to get the IP address from an alternate header variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the backend server software has any tools to take the IP address from `X-Forwarded-For` or `X-Real-IP` headers and set it as the remote address. It all depends on your backend server software or application.